# search/filter with list of string graphene-django

Tags: python, django, graphene-python, graphene-django

I am looking to search for list of different characters/string using graphene-django with single search query run.

```
      class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
          candidateInfo = graphene.List(CandidateType, search=graphene.String(), 
                                    first=graphene.Int(), 
                                    skip=graphene.Int(), last=graphene.Int(),)

          def resolve_candidateInfo(self, info, search=None, first=None, last=None, skip=None, 
                                  **kwargs):
              qs = Candidate.objects.all()
                  if search:
                  filter = (
                      Q(candidateName__icontains=search)|
                      Q(candidateEmail__icontains=search)|
                      Q(candidateSkills__icontains=search)
                  )
                  qs = qs.filter(filter)
              return qs
```

Here the candidateName, candidateSkills, candidateEmail are in Candidate class with models.CharField

With a single string/character search i am getting correct output. But it fails with list of sting/characters.

**Edited:** Adding json sample:

```
[
    {
        "model": "api.candidate",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "candidateName" : "Jack",
            "candidateEmail" : "Jack@gmail.com",
            "candidateSkills" : ["machine learning", "Artificial Intelligence"]
        }
        
    },
    {
        "model": "api.candidate",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields":{
            "candidateName" : "John",
            "candidateEmail" : "John@gmail.com",
            "candidateSkills" : ["python", "machine learning"]
        }
        
    },
    {
        "model": "api.candidate",
        "pk": 3,
        "fields":{
            "candidateName" : "Smith",
            "candidateEmail" : "Smith@gmail.com",
            "candidateSkills" : ["python"]           
        }
      
    }
]
```

If query goes in:

```
query{
        candidateInfo(search: "python")
        {

            candidateName
            candidateEmail
              
        }

}
# output must contain data of John and Smith (from sample json)
```

Also if query is

```
query{
        candidateInfo(search: ["python","artificial intelligence"])
        {

            candidateName
            candidateEmail
              
        }

}
#output must contain data of Jack, John and smith
```

**Adding models of candidate**

```
from django.db import models

class Candidate(models.Model):
    candidateName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    candidateEmail = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    candidateSkills = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.candidateSkills
```

Comment: Your fixture has: `"candidateSkills" : ["machine learning", "Artificial Intelligence"]`. We can't make sense of that as it can be the result of natural foreign key export, of which we don't know the fields, or an array field. Please post the Candidate model.

Comment: @Melvyn added models.py of Candidate. Is it helpful for you to resolve the problem. As i was trying to figure out the problem but didn't found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `for` loop as such:

```
qs = Candidate.objects.all()
    if search:
        if type(search) == list:
            qs_l = []
            for search_item in search:
                filter = (
                    Q(candidateName__icontains=search_item)|
                    Q(candidateEmail__icontains=search_item)|
                    Q(candidateSkills__icontains=search_item)
                )
                qs_l.append(qs.filter(filter))
            qs = qs_l
        else:
            filter = (
                Q(candidateName__icontains=search)|
                Q(candidateEmail__icontains=search)|
                Q(candidateSkills__icontains=search)
            )
            qs = qs.filter(filter)
return qs
```

Comment: thanks i tried with your suggestion on my query. There i tried to pass query{ candidateInfo (search: ["python","Artificial Intelligence"])  {candidateName}}. But i am not getting correct output, where i am still wrong? Added a sample json in my post above.

Comment: My bad. You need to change `search` to `search_item` inside for loop. did the necessary changes

Comment: yes i made that correct..forgot to mention in previous comment. But still it's not giving me the output.

Comment: does the object need to have all the skills in the query or any one of the skills in the query?

Comment: It can be both, like if i want to search only for "python" or it can be "python","machine learning" and also from different objects like "python","artificial intelligence". All i want to say is i want to return all those objects when i pass a query with one or many string/character from any object to be searched

Comment: i added a sample query and required output also now.

Comment: What output are you getting from the second query, using the above answer? If you can share that it will be useful

Comment: getting this error message: {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Argument \"search\" has invalid value [\"python\", \"artificial intelligence\"].\nExpected type \"String\", found [\"python\", \"artificial intelligence\"].",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 31
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Check if `search` is a list or not by printing. Then if its a list in string use `list()` method to make a list. Also check which condition its executing. The error message is not much clear

Comment: To convert search to list and pass string in it i changed in my class Query "search=graphene.List(graphene.String)" and now the error message is : {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Received incompatible instance \"<QuerySet [<Candidate: John>, <Candidate: Smith>]>\"."
    },
    {
      "message": "Received incompatible instance \"<QuerySet [<Candidate: Jack>]>\"."
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "candidateInfo": [
      null,
      null
    ]
  }
}  Didn't understood what is this?