# graphene-django full text search

Tags: django, full-text-search, graphene-python, graphene-django

I'm struggling with implementing full text search with graphene-django module. Is there a way to do this? (I'm using relays).
I want to pass search string to my get query as an additional field.

Which search engine to use is not important.

Haven't found any useful information

Comment: try to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599547/search-filter-with-list-of-string-graphene-django

Answer (score 0):

[graphene-django-filter](https://pypi.org/project/graphene-django-filter/) is your friend ! 
According to the doc, a simple implementation for full-text search is:

```
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from graphene_django_filter import AdvancedDjangoFilterConnectionField, AdvancedFilterSet

class UserFilter(AdvancedFilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            'email': ('exact', 'startswith', 'contains'),
            'first_name': ('exact', 'contains', 'full_text_search'),
            'last_name': ('exact', 'contains', 'full_text_search'),
        }

class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
        fields = '__all__'
        filterset_class = UserFilter

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    users = AdvancedDjangoFilterConnectionField(UserType)
```

Full text search API includes SearchQuery, SearchRank, and Trigram filters. SearchQuery and SearchRank filters are at the top level. If some field has been enabled for full text search then it can be included in the field array. The following query show an example of using the SearchQuery and SearchRank filters:

```
    {
  users(
    filter: {
      searchQuery: {
        vector: {
          fields: ["first_name"]
        }
        query: {
          or: [
            {value: "Bob"}
            {value: "Alice"}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ){
    edges {
      node {
        id
        firstName
        lastName  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  users(
    filter: {
      searchRank: {
        vector: {fields: ["first_name", "last_name"]}
        query: {value: "John Dou"}
        lookups: {gte: 0.5}
      }
    }
  ){
    edges {
      node {
        id
        firstName
        lastName  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Trigram filter belongs to the corresponding field. The following query shows an example of using the Trigram filter:

```
{
  users(
    filter: {
      firstName: {
        trigram: {
          value: "john"
          lookups: {gte: 0.85}
        }
      }
    }
  ){
    edges {
      node {
        id
        firstName
        lastName  
      }
    }
  }
}
```